# Hadoop TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory

Tags: hadoop, permissions

I am new to hadoop and only have a Windows machine available. On that, I have created 2 virtual machines in VirtualBox that run CentOS 6.2.

I have gone through several problems already with enabling the machines to find each other and using passwordless logins between machines etc. I am finally stuck looking at this output of the TaskTracker on both the master and the slave machine:

```
2013-08-12 12:44:47,020 WARN org.mortbay.log: Can't reuse /tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_50060_task____.2vcltf, using /tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_50060_task____.2vcltf_7889818513880644521
2013-08-12 12:44:47,705 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50060
2013-08-12 12:44:47,707 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: FILE_CACHE_SIZE for mapOutputServlet set to : 2000
2013-08-12 12:44:48,036 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
2013-08-12 12:44:51,934 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
2013-08-12 12:44:54,065 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
2013-08-12 12:44:55,177 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
2013-08-12 12:44:59,190 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
2013-08-12 12:45:03,717 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
2013-08-12 12:45:08,652 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
2013-08-12 12:45:12,115 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
```

I realise it must have something to do with my config files and my permissions etc. on the file system but I can't figure out what... I started hadoop using script start-all.sh with my dedicated hadoop user (simply called hadoop).

I have included my config files and some output from ls -l on pastebin found below.

My Hadoop Conf files:
http://pastebin.com/sAYpxi9H

Results of ls -l:
http://pastebin.com/PYCy6PvN